# StorageAccountList request works locally but not when deployed in dotnet app

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage

I have a web-api which is an App Service 'instance' and is deployed on Azure. This web-api is dotnet-core based and it uses version 6. I have another resource, Storage Accounts, where I have a couple of storage accounts which I use for my goals. My goal, at the end of the day, was to have all of those storage accounts listed and passed through my web-api to my client app. For that purpose, I used the approach recommended from the Microsoft's [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/list?tabs=dotnet#storageaccountlist):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Storage.Models;

TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

string subscriptionId = "{subscription-id}";
ResourceIdentifier subscriptionResourceId = SubscriptionResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId);
SubscriptionResource subscriptionResource = client.GetSubscriptionResource(subscriptionResourceId);

await foreach (StorageAccountResource item in subscriptionResource.GetStorageAccountsAsync())
{
    StorageAccountData resourceData = item.Data;
    Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
}

Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded");
```

This works perfectly fine and it lists all of the storage accounts but **ONLY** on a local server and when I deploy it, this functionality doesn't work. I'm using `ArmClient` for the first time and I'm assuming that the issue is somewhere with that but not 100% sure. Has any of you stumbled upon an issue like this? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is working locally is most likely because you are signed in with your credentials in either Visual Studio or Azure PowerShell/CLI and when you call `TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();`, it is making use of your credentials to execute ARM API.

However, when the same code executes in Azure more than likely you have not configured the managed identity for your web app and because of that your code is failing.

To fix this issue, you can assign a Managed Identity to your Web App and assign it proper RBAC role. Once you do that, you should not get the error.

You may find this link helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal.

Comment: And if you automate your infra deployment and want to assign the role using bicep you will find the following page very useful to find which role id to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

Comment: Thanks to both of you. If I got your answer right, I should turn the managed identity to ON for the App Service and set a role to my web-api to be able to list Storage Accounts?

Comment: That is correct. If all you want is to read the list of storage accounts, then `Reader` permission should be sufficient.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've been trying to fix this and set up `Reader` role to my web-api but I'm still facing the error. Can you provide some tutorial, if there's any, on how can I obtain this what you mentioned so I can solve my case?